# how to run the apps script project for a different sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I made a 3 sheets that i want to be run from my apps script project. At first i tried to have 3 different files in the same project but i didn't works. It's only works on the newest files app script that i made. So i made it in one files of app script project and i can't save it because the syntax is error and saying "Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier line: 27 file: Pemilihan.gs". the output that i want is that's the syntax can be run for 3 different sheets in the same spreadsheets and it's always triggered the data validation on the active cell sheets that being edit. can anyone help me for my problem?

the syntax is :

```
var wsMainName = "Pemilihan";
var wsSecondName = "Uji Fungsi (ONT)"
var wsThirdName = "Uji Fungsi (STB)"
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Pemilihan");
var wsSec = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(wsSecondName);
var wsThird = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(wsThirdName);
var wsOption = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Option");
var option = wsOption.getRange(2, 1, wsOption.getLastRow()-1, 3).getValues();
var firstLevelColumn = 4;
var secondLevelColumn= 6;
var thirdLevelColumn = 8;

function onEdit(e) {

  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName == wsMainName && c === firstLevelColumn && r > 2){
    applyFirstLevelValidation(val,r);
  }else if(wsName == wsMainName && c === secondLevelColumn && r > 2){
    applySecondLevelValidation(val,r);
  }else if (wsName == wsSecondName && c === 5 && r >2){
    applyThirdLevelValidation(val, r);
  }else (wsName === wsThirdName && c === 5 r > 2){
    applyThirdLevelValidation(val,r);
  }
}
```

Comment: All of the scripts contained by a spreadsheet have access to all of the sheets.

Answer (score 0):

#### These are getting to the appropriate functions now but I can't vouch for the rest of the functionality since I did not write it.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const names = ["Pemilihan", "Uji Fungsi (ONT)", "Uji Fungsi (STB)"];
  const idx = names.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if (~idx) {
     e.source.toast(names[idx]);
    if (idx == 0 && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.rowStart > 2) {
      applyFirstLevelValidation(e.value, e.range.rowStart);
    } else if (idx = 0 && e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart > 2) {
      applySecondLevelValidation(e.value, e.range.rowStart);
    } else if (idx == 1 && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.range.rowStart > 2) {
      applyThirdLevelValidation(e.value, e.range.rowStart);
    } else if (idx == 2 && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.range.rowStart > 2) {
      applyThirdLevelValidation(e.value, e.range.rowStart);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry but can you check my entire files project to implement the suggestion that you gave me? cause i put the syntax that you gave me and nothing happen on my spreadsheet? i'm so sorry to bother you sir.. if you don't mind this the spreadsheet file : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19B4Qq4NjztrXjCijt7Gy6XdMuDdfOqJExOk3tHXa8Ag/edit?usp=sharing . and thankyou so much for your help sir!